# What's the standard format for representing true and false values in an HTTP header?

Tags: http, http-headers

I need to add a custom header to an HTTP request, and its value's type will be boolean. However, HTTP header values are all strings. So what is the common practice for representing a boolean in this case? `0`/`1`, `false`/`true`, `False`/`True`, `off`/`on`, etc?

E.g.

```
My-Header: 1
```

Or what's generally recommended, i.e. the most commonly used convention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE: it might make the most sense to use a `header exists` vs `doesn't exist` convention as [implied here](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-adc/downloads/operations-for-http-headers.pdf)

**HTTP Header Operation** `http header .EXISTS`

> Returns a Boolean TRUE if an instance of the specified header type exists. Following is an example:
>
> http.req.header("CacheControl").exists

---

i think the answer is `?0` vs `?1`

[**Structured Field Values for HTTP > 3.3.6. Booleans**](https://httpwg.org/http-extensions/draft-ietf-httpbis-header-structure.html#name-booleans)

> Boolean values can be conveyed in Structured Fields.
>
> The ABNF for a Boolean is:
>
> > sf-boolean = "?" boolean
> >
> > boolean    = "0" / "1"
>
> A Boolean is indicated with a leading "?" character followed by a "1"
> for a true value or "0" for false. For example:
>
> > Example-Boolean: ?1

check out [`Sec-Fetch-User`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-User):

> **Syntax**
>
> Sec-Fetch-User: ?0
>
> Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
>
> **Values**
>
> The value is a Boolean Structured Header.
>
> ?0 The navigation request was triggered by a user activation.
>
> ?1 The navigation request was triggered by something other than a user
> activation.

but fwiw, [`Save-Data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Save-Data) also seems to be a standard/official "boolean" header that accepts values `"on"` vs `"off"`

[**Save-Data**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Save-Data)

> A boolean that indicates the user agent's preference for reduced data
> usage.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

> A numerical value indicating whether the client wants to opt in to
> reduced data usage mode. `on` indicates yes, while `off` (the default)
> indicates no.

also confusingly, the [ABNF page](https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/abnf/) actually says:

> boolean = ( "true" / "1" ) /
>
> ( "false" / "0" )